lidR raster creation crashing with feet projection system
I'm trying to debug an issue while processing LiDAR data in R using the lidR package (R: 4.4.0, lidR: 4.1.1). I'm trying to convert voxels to rasters with a user-defined function. I have run this successfully for multiple other lidar files that are in a meters projection system, but for some reason, I'm encountering and error for at least five datasets that use Feet.
I've successfully height normalized and processed lidar pointclouds into a voxel format and am now trying to generate rasters using user defined functions and the lidR function, "catalog_map()". When I try to run this on a high performance computing cluster, I get the following error: "Floating point exception(core dumped)"
Weirdly, I am able to get the rasters to generate locally when I try using one or two voxel files in a LAScatalog, BUT when I try to use 3 files, R crashes. I can't find anything wrong with the files themselves(they load properly and plot normally). It also doesn't seem to mater which combination of files since its only when I try 3+ that I encounter this error.
I'm pasting some minimal code down below that produces this error:
################################################################################
# Load packages ----------------------------------------------------------------
library(dplyr)
library(lidR)
library(vegan)

################################################################################
# Create functions -------------------------------------------------------------
# Point filtering 
filter_outlier = function(las)
{
  if (is(las, "LAS"))
  {
    # filter points: outliers & witheld points 
    las<- filter_poi(las, Classification != 18 & Classification != 7 & Withheld_flag != "TRUE" #& Z >= -20 & Z<117 
    )
    return(las)
  }
  
  if (is(las, "LAScatalog"))
  {
    options <- list(
      need_output_file = TRUE,    # Throw an error if no output template is provided
      need_buffer = TRUE)         # Throw an error if buffer is 0
    res <- catalog_map(las, filter_outlier, .options = options)
    return(res)
  }
}

#################################
# Set functions for LiDAR metric calculations ----------------------------------
#################################
# Intermediate Function to get from voxels to inventory function
TempList <- function(p) {
  #n <- plyr::count(p@data$Z) # pull out only the height info
  n <- plyr::count(p) # pull out only the height info
  return(n)}

# Canopy Volume Function - 4 heights (0-5, 5-15, 15-25, 25-higher)
ForestCount_FT <- function(n) {
  m <- list(
    Understory =sum((dplyr::filter(n, x>0 & x<= 16.4042))$freq),# 0-5m
    Midstory=sum((dplyr::filter(n, x> 16.4042 & x<=49.2126))$freq), # 5-15m
    SubCanopy=sum((dplyr::filter(n, x> 49.2126 & x<=82.021))$freq), # 15m-25m
    Canopy =sum((dplyr::filter(n, x> 82.021))$freq)) # >25m
  return(m)
}

# Version without Piping (since it might have an issue with LAScatalog objects)
ForestInventory_FT <- function(p){
  q <- TempList(p)
  q <- ForestCount_FT(q)
  return(q)}

# Creates an inventory of all desired metrics
vert_configuration_FT <- function(x) {
  temp <- ForestInventory_FT(x)
  
  list(mean = mean(x), 
       sd = sd(x),
       max = max(x),
       shannon = vegan::diversity(c(temp$Understory, temp$Midstory, temp$SubCanopy, temp$Canopy), index = "shannon") , # Shannon Diversity
       # simpson = vegan::diversity(c(temp$Understory, temp$Midstory, temp$SubCanopy, temp$Canopy), index = "simpson") , # Simpson Diversity
       variance = var(c(temp$Understory, temp$Midstory, temp$SubCanopy, temp$Canopy)), # Variance
       Und=temp$Understory, 
       Mid=temp$Midstory, 
       Sub=temp$SubCanopy, 
       Can=temp$Canopy
  )
  
} # end of user defined metric 

# Function for using LASCatalog 
apply_vert_configuration_FT <-function(las, res) {
  return(pixel_metrics(las, ~vert_configuration_FT(Z), res) )# calculate grid metrics
}

################################################################################
main_wd <- "data/"
LAScatalog <- readLAScatalog(paste0(main_wd,"18008") )

# Processing Settings
opt_chunk_buffer(LAScatalog) <- 98.4252 # Default is 30m/98.4252ft
# WARNING: opt_stop_early used to avoid loops breaking BUT might result in missing tiles/holes in output!! (adjust as needed)
opt_stop_early(LAScatalog) <- FALSE
# Set options for catalog_map function 
options <- list(raster_alignment = 15) # provide buffer for aligning raster 

# Create Raster outputs 
metrics <- catalog_map(LAScatalog, 
                       apply_vert_configuration_FT, # Custom function: FEET 
                       res = 16.4042, # resolution 5m / 16.4042 ft
                       .options = options)




I'm including a plot of the LAScatalog proccessing when it crashes:

Not entirely sure if it is an issue with the projection system or not, but I'm scratching my head to think of what else might be the issue. Any suggestions of diagnostics or other things to check the data for?

You need to dig further and produce and minimal (really minimal) reproducible example.  This should be reproducible without a LAScatalog loading only the problematic file and applying pixel_metric. Then the metrics itself should be reduced to minimum. Can you reproduce with e.g. mean(Z)? Then, when you have something minimal, please report a bug if it really comes from lidR. Because a crash is a bug.

At the moment, what I have posted above is the minimally reproducible example. Per your suggestion, I tried pixel_metrics(), both with mean(Z) and my own function. Both worked. I also tried a catalog_map() on a LAScatalog object with a different function from examples listed here: "https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/catalog_apply.html". That worked too.

The other thing that I've noticed is that when I try to add MORE files (4+), the "pattern of chunks" displays green for every file up until the last one. This makes me think that R is successfully processing the files but is encountering an error when trying to stitch the files together.

Then try with 2 files only. And try with ´catalog_apply´ instead of ´catalog_map´. This will skip the final merging. Let see how it works.

use terra::vrt on the list of files produced

Perfect! Really appreciate it! catalog_apply and terra::merge seems to do the trick!
